# cant show data using EJS inside Placeholder

Tags: node.js, forms, mongoose, ejs

i am trying to show data using EJS inside a placeholder (FORM),
here is my code:

```
<input class="input" type="text" placeholder="name: <%= user.firstName %>" id="name" required>
```

on the site, i can see "user:" but nothing more, 
and i put the ejs outside the placeholder it work just fine .

Answer (score 0):

try

```
value= <%= user.firstName %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap "placeholder=" in ejs tags as well, like below.

```
<input type="text" <%="placeholder="%><%=user.firstName%>>
```